# How to add a hyperlink to another cell from an image using openpyxl?

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I've added an image to an xlsx file via openpyxl. Now, I also wanted to add a hyperlink to the same image (similar as adding a hyperlink to a cell, but I need to add it to an image), such that when you click it, it will call/reference another cell in the same sheet or in another sheet of that same file.

My code for adding the image works well, but I couldn't come up with a code to add a hyperlink to it.

I tried this:

```
img.hyperlink = '=HYPERLINK("{}", "{}")'.format('A1', '')
```

Comment: Can do with Xlwings but would take a bit of research to determine if it could be achieved with Openpyxl.